# Вопрос про перебор массива в php

Tags: php

Вопрос:

Есть массив a = array(тут много элементов). Проходим по массиву циклом
`for (i=0; i<=count(a); i++)`. Можно ли как-нибудь ускорить цикл?

Ответ:

1) Вынести count(a) в отдельную переменную

2) Считать массив с конца циклом `for (i=count(a); i>=0; i--)`

1. Мне кажется или в условии ошибка и при `<=` count (больше или равно) цикл будет выполняться вечно?
2. Почему если бежать по массиву с конца будет быстрее?

Comment: Зачем вам ускорять циклы перебора массивов на PHP? Потом ведь этот код нужно поддерживать. А самый очевидный способ перебора массива `foreach ($arr as $v) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мне кажется или в условии ошибка и при `<= count` (больше или равно) цикл будет выполняться вечно?

во первых меньше или равно, во вторых цикл не будет вечным, так как `i` у вас все же увеличивается каждую итерацию и так или иначе условие выполнится. Единственная проблема тут, что он выполнится на 1 раз больше, чем надо с доступом к лишнему элементу.

> Почему если бежать по массиву с конца будет быстрее?

Формально не важно с какой стороны проходить массива с начала или с конца. Вопрос в проверке условия. Условие `i <= count` выполняется на каждой итерации, то есть функция `count` выполняется каждый раз. В случае прохода с конца, `count` выполняется единожды для присваивания начального значения `i`.  В случае если вынести `len = count(a)` перед циклом, и написать условие `i < len` то скорость будет одинакова.